# When is return-value optimization used?

Tags: c++, optimization, memory

In the code snippet below, I have a class that holds a vector, and a getter to access it. When I compile my code with optimizations turned on, I would have expected that the call to get_value() would be optimized out, and one accesses directly the data. Instead, the process is slow, and a quick profiling shows that there's a lot of memory copying going on.

```
class Data {
  public:
   std::vector<double> get_value() const { return value_; }
  private:
   std::vector<double> value_;
};

Data ex(...); //pass value
for (unsigned i=0; i<ex.get_value().size(); ++i) {
   //do things with
   ex.get_value()[i];
}
```

Question 1: Why is that?

Question 2: How do I fix it? For this question, I have two answers which don't satisfy me. The first possibility is to store the value locally before the loop. But that involves a copy, and if there are a lot of different values to get, that would involve a lot of setup, which is bad coding practice. The second possibility would be to perform this loop in a member function of the class. But if the function is not conceptually related to the class and just needs to use it, that would also be bad coding practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Question 1: Why is that?

Because `ex.value_` still needs have the same state after you have called `ex.get_value()`. RVO is safe in the same circumstances that `std::move` is safe, i.e. when it doesn't matter that you are modifying an object, because it is about to be destroyed.

> Question 2: How do I fix it?

Have `Data::get_value` return a const reference.

Alternatively:

```
class Data {
  public:
   template<typename UnaryFunctor>
   UnaryFunctor use_value(UnaryFunctor && uf) const 
   { for (double v: value_) { uf(v); } return uf; }
  private:
   std::vector<double> value_;
};
```

Here we have a template that performs the loop, but takes the body of the loop as a parameter. It also returns the (potentially stateful) function object as its result.

Comment: The const isn't necessary but it is almost certainly best practice for a getter, so +1 for that.

Comment: @Neil `get_value` is already a const method, it can't return a non-const reference to `value_`. I almost posted a version that suggested overloading the getter for constness

Comment: True, but you could have just as easily removed the const keyword on the method to resolve the conflict.  Always better to maintain const if possible.

Comment: But why is it that if you use ex.get_value() as an rvalue (as in my example if I'm not mistaken), you don't get rvo?